# Where does `billlable` come from in Laravel Spark's `update-payment-method-stripe` Component?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-spark

If Laravel Spark, there's a vue component with the following inline template

```
<spark-update-payment-method-stripe :user="user" :team="team" :billable-type="billableType" inline-template>
    /* ... */
            <div class="pull-right">
                <span v-if="billable.card_last_four">
                    <i :class="['fa', 'fa-btn', cardIcon]"></i>
                    ************@{{ billable.card_last_four }}
                </span>
            </div>
    /* ... */
</spark-update-payment-method-stripe>
```

This template include the variable `billable.card_last_four`.

If I track down the definition file for the component, I see this

```
#File: resources/assets/js/spark-components/settings/payment-method/update-payment-method-stripe.js
var base = require('settings/payment-method/update-payment-method-stripe');

Vue.component('spark-update-payment-method-stripe', {
    mixins: [base]
});
```

and if I track down the base component, I see a vue component defined

```
#File: spark/resources/assets/js/settings/payment-method/update-payment-method-stripe.js
module.exports = {
    props: ['user', 'team', 'billableType'],
/* ... */
```

However, none of these components seem to define `billable` anywhere.  I see a lot of references to `this.billable`.

```
#File: spark/resources/assets/js/settings/payment-method/update-payment-method-stripe.js
/* ... */

this.form.address = this.billable.billing_address;
this.form.address_line_2 = this.billable.billing_address_line_2;
this.form.city = this.billable.billing_city;
this.form.state = this.billable.billing_state;
this.form.zip = this.billable.billing_zip;
this.form.country = this.billable.billing_country || 'US';

/* ... */                
placeholder() {
    if (this.billable.card_last_four) {
        return `************${this.billable.card_last_four}`;
    }

    return '';
}
/* ... */
```

Where does this `billable` property come from?  I assume Vue's doing some form of meta-programming and/or magic to populate this, but I'm not familiar enough with Vue to know what's going on.

Comment: Is this on github somewhere?

Comment: @thanksd Yes and No.  Laravel Spark is a private repository for paying customers

Comment: Possibly a plugin defined somewhere. Could search for Vue.use

Comment: Or it could be a [computed property](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Basic-Example) (not sure how unfamiliar with Vue you are)

Comment: @BertEvans Thank you, I didn't know about plugins.  They don't look to be the culprits here (no Vue.use calls) but good to know!

Comment: @thanksd Thank you!  There's a section for computed properties -- but no `billable`.  However, the Vue Chrome debugger says billable **is** a computed property -- can computer properties be defined on a component (or set of component) globally or non-locally?  (very unfamiliar with Vue)

Comment: Is there an `extends` property on `base`?

Comment: Or does the base use mixins? Computed properties defined in mixins get assigned to the component using that mixin

Comment: Thanks both -- see answer below.  Looks like Spark's using  Vue.mixin to add some mixins globally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got the answer I was looking for with help from [Bert Evans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/38065/bert-evans) and [thanksd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2678454/thanksd) above, as well as the [Chrome VueJS debugger](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools)

The `billable` property was, indeed, a computed property.  However, it wasn't computed locally in the `update-payment-method-stripe.js` definition file.  Instead, Spark has a `vue-bootstrap.js` which contains the following

```
Vue.mixin(require('./mixin'));
```

It turns out VueJS has a [global mixin](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html#Global-Mixin) feature which (appears to?) add a method to every component in the system.  The `mixin` module looks like this

```
#File: spark/resources/assets/js/mixin.js
module.exports = {
    computed: {
        /**
         * Get the billable entity.
         */
        billable() {
            /* ... */
        },
        /* ... */
    }
};
```

Which means every component in spark will have this computer `billable` property.